# How to use global static variable in c++

Tags: c++

I have `static int defaultvalue = 1` in my `.cpp file` and I have a `static class function` like this which uses the global static variable `defaultvalue` in the same file.

```
//static function
    int Myclass::func(int rate)
    {
        int finalrate = defaultvalue;
        switch(rate)
        {    
            case 2:
                finalrate=2;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }    
        return finalrate;
    }
```

When I tried to compile this.I got an error saying `undefined reference to Myclass::defaultvalue.`

Can some one help me out.Thanks.

Comment: try ::defaultvalue will specify the global namespace

Comment: You may need to declare it as extern if it is in a different file.

Comment: They are in the same file

Comment: "How to use global static variable in c++" - just don't.

Comment: The compiler is looking for `Myclass::defaultvalue`, but it doesn't sound like `defaultvalue` is a member of `Myclass`. Anyway, this code is silly. There's no reason to use a global variable here, or just about anywhere else.

Comment: static int defaultvalue = 1 ;  - if it is in another cpp file it will not be visible, that is what static before var means, the correct design is to put static const int defaultvalue = 1 ; inside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it as extern in h and then declare it's "body" in .cpp.

For your case :

in the .h

```
extern int defaultValue;
```

in the .cpp

```
int MyClass::defaultValue=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If that variable is defined in a different module, then you will have to use the `extern` keyword in your current module ahead of any references to it, e.g.,

```
extern int defaultValue;
```

That will notify the compiler that it is defined elsewhere. At least one module should have a non-extern definition

```
int defaultvalue;
```

or the linked will be unhappy.

Alternately, you could put a constant definition in a `.h` file, and `#include` that `.h` file in each of your `.cpp` sources. For example:

```
// File defval.h
const int defaultvalue = 42;
```

and then in your source, use

```
#include defval.h
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just put it in the class:

```
class Myclass
{
  public:
     static int func(int rate);
     static const int defaultvalue = 1 ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that te best approach is to put static member into class and then not forget to initialize it in cpp file.

```
file.h
class Myclass
{
  public:
     static int func(int rate);
     static int defaultvalue;
};

file.cpp
int MyClass::defaultValue=0;
int Myclass::func(int rate)
{
...
}
```